# Error in creating new file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run this code in irb:

```
File.open('j1.txt','w') {|f| f.write("doc1223423")}
```

it works successfully. But when I do the same in a method in my controller, it gives the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - file location as specified )
```

Why does it do that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path of the file? If the error does not occur when you use the absolute path, it's possible that your controller is just not able to find the file from where it's located.

Comment: @Vic: Yeah...i tried the absolute path but the problem was still there, which now i have finally solved. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Vic : The problem was I was trying to access a file location which didn't existi.e lets say i was trying to access/create a file j.txt in the directory blah(which i was assuming will be created automatically when the file is created) which didn't exist. So, before creating the file, i created a empty directory and then created the file. Hope I am able to help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved.
The above file location that i was specifying didn't exist.
I was doing something like this

```
File.open ("#{RAILS_ROOT}/jatin/j.txt", 'w+') do |f|
      f.write("blah")
    end
```

but the directory /jatin/ was not there, so the solution was to first create the directory and then create the file.

```
Dir::mkdir("#{RAILS_ROOT}/jatin")
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

Try chagning `'w'` to `'w+'` - this will create a new file, `'w'` just opens an existing one for writing (updating).

Here's a good round of examples that might help:

- http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/fileaccess.html

Comment: Try using a specific path that you have write permissions to, such as `/tmp/j1.txt` (if on Unix) or `c:/windows/temp/j1.txt` (if on Windows).

Comment: The only thing "w+" does is open the file for reading in addition to writing, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode

Comment: @Shannon From the page you linked: "w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for reading and writing.

Comment: @icyrock.com From the same page: "w" "Write-only, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for writing." 
They both truncate or create, contrary to what you say in your answer. I guess I should have said, "the only thing it does **differently**".